# Find edges part of a simple path between two vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose G is an undirected graph. How can I efficiently find all edges in G that are part of a simple path between given vertices A and B?

Comment: Do you want to enumerate all paths from $A \to B$? Or do you want all the edges in a single path? Given a path, just traverse it and collect the edges. Enumerating all the paths can be difficult.

Comment: The output should be a subset S of edges in G such that each s in S is an edge on SOME simple path from A to B. Obviously, this can be done by enumerating the simple paths from A to B, but I am hoping for a solution that computes S efficiently.

Comment: My gut says that this is $\mathcal{NP}$-Hard. Suppose the only $A-B$ path is a Hamiltonian Path. Then finding all the edges in this path can be used to construct the path itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b \in V(G)$, and $e \in E(G)$. Then $e$ is on some path from $a$ to $b$ in $G$ if and only if $a$, $b$, and $e$ are in the same component in $G$ and $e$ is in a biconnected component that is on the unique path from the biconnected component containing $a$ to the biconnected component containing $b$ in the block tree for $G$.

*Proof*: Suppose $a$, $b$, and $e$ are in the same component in $G$ and $e$ is in a biconnected component $B_e$ that is on the unique path from the biconnected component $B_a$ containing $a$ to the biconnected component $B_b$ containing $b$ in the block tree for $G$. If $B_a \neq B_e$, find a path $P_a$ in $G$ internally disjoint from $B_e$ from $a$ to a vertex $a'$ in $B_e$. If $B_a = B_e$, let $a' = a$, and $P_a = a$. Similarly, if $B_b \neq B_e$, find a path $P_b$ in $G$ internally disjoint from $B_e$ from $b$ to a vertex $b'$ in $B_e$. If $B_b = B_e$, let $b' = b$, and $P_b = b$. Now if $e = a'b'$, then $P_a \cup e \cup P_b$ is a path from $a$ to $b$ in $G$. If $e$ is incident with $a'$ or $b'$, then by Menger's theorem find two disjoint paths in $B_e$ from the ends of $e$ to whichever of $a'$ or $b'$ is not incident with $e$, then one of these paths together with $e$, $P_a$ and $P_b$ is a path from $a$ to $b$ containing $e$. Finally, if neither $a'$ nor $b'$ are ends of $e$, by Menger's Theorem, there are two disjoint paths in $B_e$ from $a'$ and $b'$ to the ends of $e$, and these two paths together with $e$, $P_a$ and $P_b$ is a path from $a$ to $b$ containing $e$.

Conversely, if $e$ is not in the same component as $a$ and $b$, clearly there is no path from $a$ to $b$ containing $e$, and if $B_e$ is not on the path in the block tree for $G$ from $B_a$ to $B_b$, there cannot be a path from $a$ to $e$ that is disjoint from a path from $b$ to $e$, and hence there cannot be a path from $a$ to $b$ containing $e$. $\Box$

See, for example, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) for definitions, and also an algorithm that determines biconnected components in linear time. Using this result and that algorithm, it should be possible to find all such edges in linear time.

Comment: I think the last sentence of the first paragraph of your proof is incorrect. Menger's theorem tells us that there is a path from a' to one vertex of e and a path from b' to the other vertex of e. But it does not guarantee that these paths use disjoint vertices (as they come from different applications of Menger's theorem). So this does not (in general) give us a simple path from a' to b' through e.

Comment: @user2562540 Let $X = \{a',b'\}$ and let $Y$ be the set of ends of $e$. Since $B_e$ is 2-connected, Menger's Theorem guarantees there will be two disjoint paths in $B_e$ from $X$ to $Y$. See for example, Theorem 3.3.1 from Section 3.3 in Diestel, here: http://diestel-graph-theory.com/basic.html